# How to properly display Pytorch's math notation inside docstring?

Tags: python, pytorch, docstring

When looking at the docstring of Pytorch functions, the math notations are not properly displayed, e.g.: 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html

```
.. math::
    \text{loss}(x, class) = weight[class] \left(-x[class] + \log\left(\sum_j \exp(x[j])\right)\right)
```

Only if I use my IDE to display the documentation, it renders the latex notation properly.

Is there any switch for displaying math on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs in source code won't render unless you try some script injection via Greasemonkey or so.
But first have a look at the standard docs where you can find the [rendered formula](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=threshold#l1loss).